# Set an JTextField's »disabledTextColor« to RED and disabled it setting »enabled« to false, but it still shows up GRAY

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, jtextfield

I'am using NetBeans and its WindowDesigner.

Having set focus to an **JTextField** I did two things in the Properties window:

- First I set the TextField's **disabledTextColor** field to a red ( [0, 0, 51] ),
- Second I set the TextField's **enabled** field to false.

Viewing the preview, nothing. Still plain gray.
Why is that and how can I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must have another issue, these basic Swing methods works for me

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InactiveBackgroundTest {

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        JTextField s0 = new JTextField("Very long Text");
        s0.setEnabled(true);
        s0.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        s0.setBackground(Color.blue);
        //UIManager.put("FormattedTextField.inactiveBackground", Color.RED);

        JTextField s1 = new JTextField("Very long Text");
        s1.setEnabled(false);
        s1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        s1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        s1.setDisabledTextColor(Color.yellow);

        JTextField s2 = new JTextField("Very long Text");
        s2.setEditable(false);
        s2.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        s2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        s2.setDisabledTextColor(Color.yellow);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.black);
        p.add(s0);
        p.add(s1);
        p.add(s2);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new InactiveBackgroundTest().makeUI());
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @B. Lauing not, never, please I wouldn't want to be constrained by the methods implemented to the Framework, by the way, most of methods are accesible by WindowBuilder too, two ways `1)` correctly override proper method in the popup properties, `2)` edit code in the CodeEditor

Comment: @mKorbel is correct. It's also possible to edit the GUI designer's properties to produce the desired generated code, but you have to know _a prori_ what to edit. There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2785876/230513). Metaphorically, learn carpentry _then_ learn the power saw.